# Make radio buttons required in Angular 10

Tags: angular, validation, radio-button, radio-group

I have 2 two-option questions with radio buttons as answers. How can I make radio buttons required, so that if they are not answered a message be shown?

[This article](https://codezup.com/angular-7-8-9-10-radio-button-example/) explains how to require radio buttons, but there is only one questions, if I add the second question it does not work!

Here is my .html file:

```html
<form [formGroup]="surveyForm" >          
    <table class="table" >
      <tbody >
        <tr> Question1 </tr>                
        <tr>  <input type="radio" value="1" formControlName="ans1" id="ans1.opt1"  required > a
              <input type="radio" value="2" formControlName="ans1" id="ans1.opt2"  required > b    
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <div class="form-control alert alert-danger" id="ans1Error" style="display: none;"></div>
              <div *ngIf="isValidInput('ans1')" class="alert alert-danger">
                 <div *ngIf="surveyForm.controls['ans1'].errors?.required">   
                    Answer is required.
                  </div>
               </div>
          </tr>
          <tr> Question2 </tr>                
          <tr>  <input type="radio" value="1" formControlName="ans2" id="ans2.opt1"  required > a
                <input type="radio" value="2" formControlName="ans2" id="ans2.opt2"  required > b            
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <div class="form-control alert alert-danger" id="ans2Error"  style="display: none;"></div>
              <div *ngIf="isValidInput('ans2')" class="alert alert-danger">
                  <div *ngIf="surveyForm.controls['ans2'].errors?.required">   
                    <p> Answer is required.</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
     <button  [disabled]="!surveyForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  > Submit </button>   
</form>
```

and .ts file:

```ts
  surveyForm!: FormGroup; 
  surveyInfo!: {
  ans1: number;
  ans2: number;          
   };
 
  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }
  initForm(): void {
    this.surveyForm = this.fb.group({
      ans1: ['', Validators.required],
      ans2: ['', Validators.required],                  
    });
  }

  isValidInput(fieldName: any): boolean {
    return this.surveyForm.controls[fieldName].invalid &&
      (this.surveyForm.controls[fieldName].dirty || this.surveyForm.controls[fieldName].touched);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works to the extent that the form is doing what you're asking of it.

If you are saying that you don't know why you aren't seeing the error messages, it's because there's no native way to deselect a radio input. Therefore, when you click the radio input, it has a value, which satisfies the `Validators.required` requirement.

Also, you've disabled the submit button if the form isn't valid. If it wasn't disabled, you could run another validity check on submit and display an error there.

[Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-demo-reactive-forms-tnpekb?file=src/app/app.component.ts) showing your form state.

---

Edit:
The example you link to does this:

```html
 <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && myForm.invalid">
     <p>Please select either Gender</p>
  </div>
```

And the submit function is this:

```js
  templateForm(form: NgForm) {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (!form.valid) {
      return false;
    } else {
      alert(JSON.stringify(form.value))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Meqwz. Yes I want to see an error if the radio buttons are not selected, So if I enable the submit button, then which other validity I can use?

Comment: Also I'm not familiar with  stackblitz ... the link is an empty page for me! No idea how to use it!

Comment: Added the example from the tutorial you link to.